# iPhone - how to select from a collection of UILabels?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a few UILabels, any one of which will update according to the index of an NSArray index they represent. I thought of selecting them by their tag

```
self.displayLabel.tag = myArray[index];
```

but that changes the tag value to whatever my array is holding at the moment

Using a dictionary for whatever tricks it offers instead of an NSArray doesn't help because i still have to select the correct matching label. This is the effect i want to achieve.

```
self.|mySelectedLabel|.text = myArray[index];
```

what should i put in |mySelectedLabel| to get the one i'm looking for?

I'm almost ashamed to ask at my reputation level, but this is stymie-ing me
every search only turns up how to set Labels and change, not the process of selecting

Comment: I should add, that i want to avoid having to do a Switch Case within my method, I just want to do it generically as the array might be 14 elements in size

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set the tags to the appropriate index to match your
 array indices you can use `[self.view viewWithTag:index]`;

Comment: This might be what i'm looking for, I'll get back in a few days on this as Looking through the Apple Docs is not so easy on the usage of any method. What they call syntax seems end up different in real use. It seems to be more of a memory-jog for those who know than instruction for the newcomer.

Comment: Not a good idea, because what do you do for the index 0? This is the default tag for all views, so you might not get the label with that tag.

Comment: Good point.  You can offset the tags by one `[self.view viewWithTag:index+1];`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not setting the tag with:

```
self.displayLabel.tag = index;
```

Also, you could just loop though an array of labels and find the right one:

```
for (UILabel *label : labelArray) {
    if (label.tag == index) {
        label.text = @"I found you!";
    }
}
```

Comment: the tag is already set, so self.displayLabel.tag = index; changes nothing. Regards your second comment I'd have to have a loop looking through an array of labels nested inside a loop of myArray looking for things that require updating. hmm. would work, but is there something simpler?

Comment: Yeah, I think Paulw11 hit the nail on the head there

Comment: This will not give you the correct view for an index value of 0; as 0 is the default tag for views.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using tags you can refer to your specific textfields by reference:

```
// Create an array to hold your textfields
NSMutableArray *textFields = [NSMutableArray array]

// Create your textfields and add them to the array
UITextField *textField;
for (NSUInteger idx = 0: idx++; idx < numberOfTextFieldsYouWant) {
    textField = [UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:<whateverYouWant>];
    [textFields addObject:textField];
}
```

Since you are adding the objects to an array, rather than using the tag value 0, 1, 2... you can just access it by it's index in the array

So, for what you want to do you can just do:

```
textfields[index].text = myArray[index];
```

It's a lot cleaner, doesn't rely on magic tags, and you have an array of all your dynamic textfields that you can remove, or change in one place.

I think tags are vastly overused, and they aren't necessary in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Just letting you know I reframed the problem and this eventually worked for me without having to use an array
( with endless experimenting, I sort of bumped into it so I don't know if it constitutes good technique )

the desired label corresponding to the bag weight ( one of a number possible ) displays the right update

```
- (IBAction)acceptWeight:(UIButton *)sender {
   int tempValue = (int) currentWeight;
  // current weight comes from a UISegementedController

   for (UILabel *labels in self.view.subviews) 
   {
      if (labels.tag == currentWeight) 
      {
         bags[tempValue]++;
         labels.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",bags[tempValue]];
      }
   }
  totalKilo = totalKilo + (int)currentWeight;
  self.totalKilo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",totalKilo];
}
```