# substituting an NSString as an object for selecting

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class 'Membership' for which i create 10 member objects in my VC

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) Membership *member1;
@property (nonatomic,strong) Membership *member2;
..
@property (nonatomic,strong) Membership *member10;
```

and these are held in an

```
NSArray *membersArray;
```

which is periodically saved to file. In places my code needs to deal with those objects generically. How to select them is the problem

```
for (int idx=0; idx<10; idx++ {

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"self.member%d.name",idx];
str = nameField.text;
}

// further code edited out due to comment request for clarification
```

doesn't show an error but obviously isn't going to work. str holds the name, but the object itself doesn't.

How is it done? 
I could write a function for each member and send program flow through switch cases, and that may be OK if there were only 2 or 3 members but for 10 that's just ungainly

Comment: Your question as it stands is fairly confusing. What are you trying to accomplish? Are you keeping track of your members in both an `NSArray` *and* as individual properties? Are you asking about `for` loops?

Comment: I'll try to make it clear by editing. the substitution is required in separate places. For brevity i lumped them together

Comment: It's basically silly to create identical properties member1, member2... when they will be referenced by index -- They should be elements in an NSMutableArray.

Comment: it is in fact a similar problem to what i had (and never fully resolved) in another project : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649867/iphone-how-to-select-from-a-collection-of-uilabels/22649968#22649968

Answer (score 1):

Don't declare separate properties for each `Membership`. Instead, make the `membersArray` a property, and then access individual ones with subscripts, remembering that array subscripts are `0`-based--in other words, your current `member1` can be accessed at `self.membersArray[0]`.

Comment: Does the array need to be a property of the Membership class or the View Controller? In any case i get: Property 'name' not found on object of type 'NSArray *'

Comment: It doesn't have to be a property, but there's no reason for it not to be one. It's unrelated to the problem you're having--you're trying to get the name for an element in the array, not from the array itself. self.membersArray[0].name should work.