# Swift equivalent of UILabel access

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

This worked for me in Objective C, but i can't for the life of me get it to work in Swift:

```
- (IBAction)acceptWeight:(UIButton *)sender {
   int tempValue = (int) currentWeight;
  // current weight comes from a UISegementedController

   for (UILabel *labels in self.view.subviews) 
   {
      if (labels.tag == currentWeight) 
      {
         bags[tempValue]++;
         labels.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",bags[tempValue]];
      }
   }
  totalKilo = totalKilo + (int)currentWeight;
  self.totalKilo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",totalKilo];
}
```

I'm trying to generically access one of a number of UILabels dynamically, and update its contents.

There is a tool i tried here [ojectivec2swift.net](http://www.ojectivec2swift.net) but while t'was a brave attempt at conversion, it didn't cut the mustard

it gives

```
labels.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",bags[tempValue]];
```

as this equivalent:

```
labels.text = "\(bags[tempValue])"
// compiler warns.. Cannot assign to 'text' in 'labels'
```

disclosure: this is based on a question i asked here:
[iPhone - how to select from a collection of UILabels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649867/iphone-how-to-select-from-a-collection-of-uilabels/22649968#22649968)
( and in the end none of the answers quite did it for me so i eventually experimented my way round. ) All my recent swift-related searches discuss not-quite-fitting approaches

---

EDIT:
for the sake of completeness [and as requested] here's the whole swift code function in context

```
    @IBAction func acceptWeight(sender: UIButton)  {
    var tempValue: Int = currentWeight

    for labels: UILabel in self.view.subviews {
        if labels.tag == currentWeight {
          bags[tempValue]++
          labels.text = "\(bags[tempValue])"
      }
   }
   totalKilo = totalKilo + currentWeight
    self.totalKilo.text = "\(totalKilo)"
}
```

Comment: The Objective-C code you posted is not helpful and does not add to the discussion.  Try replacing that code with your actual full Swift implementation if you want any help resolving this problem.  You've posted a single line of Swift and an error message.  You haven't shown us the context in which the error appears.  You're asking us to guess the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the assumptions that all subviews are UILabel. As soon as you add a button, it will break. Try this:

```
@IBAction func acceptWeight(sender: UIButton)  {
    var tempValue = currentWeight

    for subview in self.view.subviews {
        if let label = subview as UILabel where label.tag == currentWeight {
          bags[tempValue] += 1
          label.text = "\(bags[tempValue])"
      }
   }
   totalKilo = totalKilo + currentWeight
   self.totalKilo.text = "\(totalKilo)"
}
```

Comment: Yes! it worked!! but you are right in being aware of the tag values of other UI elements in the view. Strangely that one line I singled out works now where before it didn't.  I just have to puzzle over how to elegantly clear their text when they don't apply to the If ( … ) condition. Thanks.